# Joining elements in list of Strings in loop with a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Every 2 elements should be joined in a loop till the end of the list
This is what i have been trying to do

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
for i in range(len(items)+1):
  items[i]=items[i]+items[i+1]
  i=i+2
print(items)
```

**Expected Output: ['ab' , 'cd' , 'ef' , 'gh' , 'ij']**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can supply another argument to [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to specify the increment ("step"):

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
res = []
for i in range(0, len(items), 2):
    res.append(items[i] + items[i + 1])
print(res)
# ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij']
```

Or, better yet, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead:

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
items = [items[i] + items[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(items), 2)]
print(items)
# ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using list comprehension like this:

```
items = [items[i] + items[i+1] for i in range(0, len(items), 2)]
```

Comment: If I can use `join` instead: `[''.join(items[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(items), 2)]`

Answer (score 1):

A solution with regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
>>> re.findall('.{1,2}', ''.join(items))
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij']
```

Comment: The limitation here is it assumes the elements of the list are single characters. But, +1 anyway, for handling the odd-length list case nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Your thought process is correct, I would double check your print statement.  You are printing items, but are updating items[i] to items[i] + items[i+1]. I believe you want to print the variable you are updating.

Comment: No, it's not. Setting `i` inside the for-loop has no effect on the next value it takes on. Still runs with i consecutively set to every integer `range(len(items)+1)`. (which should actually be `range(len(items)-1)`)

Comment: I thought he had the print in the loop. You're correct.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know that `len()` returns the **number** of item, not the size of the array (remember that the array index starts at 0). [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), if you want, you can look at the docs for the `len()` function.

Next, just to inform you, you can use the method `append()` to insert an object into the final position of the array. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) you can find some info on arrays.

Moreover, I want to add that in python, when using `range`, you can take advantage of the `step` value that you can pass to range: `range(start, stop, step)`. You can read more about it [here](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/python-2.6.9-docs-html/library/functions.html).

Said so, I would do something as follow:

```
output=[]
for i in range(0, len(items), 2):
    output.append(items[i]+items[i+1]);
print(output)
```